# How to get rid of a LVM partition when switching distributions?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, xubuntu

**Background**

I am an inexperienced Linux user. I want to install Mint on a computer that currently has Xubuntu. I want to install on my SSD drive, which is a secondary hard drive because of hardware reasons out of my control. My primary hard drive is a regular hard drive on which I keep data. The installer wanted to install Mint on the primary hard drive so I picked the "Something else" option to manually select where to install it and I now have to setup partitions. The issue is that when I installed Xubuntu on my SSD the installation process created a logical partition that occupies the entire disk. And that is blocking me from modifying any partitions on my SSD. [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Y21.jpg)

**Question**

My question is how do I get rid of the logical volume so that I can setup partitions for my Mint installation?

Comment: I don't know specifically about Mint, but most installer allow you to drop in a command line shell, just use it and try @Serge's command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE This will make your current installation un-bootable and any data in the volume group inaccessible.**

first in a terminal window start

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

then press `d` (the partition delete command)

then press `3` (the number of partition to delete)

then press `w` (write changes and exit)